# Receiving 2 HTTP request where only 1 was send

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on a practice project in which I work with Express, Mongo and Mongoose. I am creating a basic CRUD structure so that I can add the fancy stuff later.

My `http://localhost:3000/campgrounds` route shows all the different campgrounds listed underneath each other. Each campground is an `a` link pointing to the details page found at the route `http://localhost:3000/campgrounds/123`. To find the specific campground, I am using the express function `findById()`. However, the app crashes when I enter that page.

The problem is that `req.params.id` is returning 2 values. The first value is always correct as I go to the correct page, but then it returns another `null` value which crashes the Node program. I have no idea why it is returning 2 values, so I am hoping one of you can help me!

Currently, I have included an `if` statement in the `app.get` route to `http://localhost:3000/campgrounds/:id`. This prevents the app from crashing, but chrome continues loading the page infinitely.

### My index file

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Campground = require('./models/campground');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/yelp-camp');

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", () => {
    console.log("database connected");
});

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// Setting the route to our homepage
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
});

// Setting the route to the page that displays all campgrounds
app.get('/campgrounds', async (req, res) => {
    // Getting all our different campgrounds
    const campgrounds = await Campground.find({});

    // Rendering the campgrounds index EJS template, and sending back the campgrounds found
    res.render('campgrounds/index', { campgrounds });
});

// Setting the route to the details page of a single campgrounds
app.get('/campgrounds/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    console.log(id);

    if (id !== 'null') {
        try {
            const campground = await Campground.findById(id);
            res.render('campgrounds/show', { campground });
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Serving on port 3000');
});
```

The problem is occurring when I am setting the route to the details page of a single campground. I am currently just forcing a value in to check whether the `findById()` is functioning correctly, and it is. And my console.log is returning the 2 values like I have already stated. First the correct id, and then a `null` value.

### My schema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CampgroundSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    price: String,
    description: String,
    location: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Campground', CampgroundSchema);
```

### EJS file `campgrounds/show`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Campground: <%= campground.title %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Campground: <%= campground.title %></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

### EJS file `campgrounds/index`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Campgrounds</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>All campgrounds</h1>
        <ul>
            <!-- Looping over our campgrounds and creating a li for each -->
            <% for(let campground of campgrounds) { %>
            <li><a href="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>"><%= campground.title %></a></li>
            <% } %>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

### The question

Why is req.params.id returning 2 values, and not just one? There is only 1 id so why should it return a `null` value as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide `campgrounds/show.ejs` content

Comment: Hi @hoangdv, the EJS file is at the bottom of my post. I found out that it is normal behavior for `req.params.id` to return 2 values, so something else must be going wrong in my code.

Comment: Actually it is not normal behavior for `req.params.id` to return 2 values. Man am I confused right now lol.

Comment: Sounds like you've got something making multiple requests to your _campground_ route. First place I'd look is in your `campgrounds/index` view file (unless there's more to `campgrounds/show` that you haven't shown)

Comment: Hi Phil, thank you for your answer. I have included the `campgrounds/index` file in my original post. The `campgrounds/show` hasn't changed and is exactly as it is in the main file. Is it possible that I have 2 instances of the server running which is why `req.params.id` is making multiple requests? If yes, is there a way to validate this issue?

Comment: Is that literally all there is to your `.ejs` files? You don't have any CSS, JS or images? Can you please describe the actions you take to reproduce the issue (eg open <url>, click on <link> and it goes to <url> then this happens...)

Comment: Yes, I am busy creating the basic CRUD structure before I start adding the fancy stuff. What happens is that I am on my localhost/campgrounds page which has all the different campgrounds listed. I then click on one of the campgrounds and it takes me to the `campgrounds/show` page for that campground. The chrome tab then keeps on loading, and `console.log` prints 2 values (the id, and the `null`) to the console.

Comment: The continuous loading can probably be solved by sending a response when the `id` is null or there's an error... `res.status(400).send("No ID provided");`. Also, use your dev-tools _Network_ panel to inspect the requests. I suspect _something_ is making a request to `/campgrounds/null` (or similar). If that's all the EJS code, it could be a browser extension

Comment: It looks like something is making a request to /campgrounds/null. When I block it the program is functioning as per the expected way. The initiator of this `null` request is `http://localhost:3000/campgrounds/64f763ae585b41f59f85c7c5`, which also happens to be the request that actually has to load the page... uff so confusing lol

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue... For every request, 2 HTTP requests were being sent because of a bad Chrome extension that I had installed. Uninstalled the Chrome extension and everything is working as it is supposed to!

I managed to solve the problem by testing different variables in a secluded environment. I also saw, with the help of the Chrome developer tools, that the issue was occurring every time after the extension was called. Maybe this can help somebody else with a similar problem!